# How to get raw data from observable getting from ngrx selector

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using awesome ngrx store management library in my project. So, to get data in the component I am using @Select() from ngrx/store and this function is returning observable. Currently, I am facing difficulty to get raw data from the observable

In my code, observable is returning a list of user details that I am displaying in the HTML table. The table has few functionalities like sorting, filtering. The difficulty is to sort the data based on the column which I am displaying in the table and for that I want to get raw data instead of observable to sort.

```
@Select(UserState.userList) userList$; 

<thead>
    <tr>
        <td (click)="sortByName()">
            Name
        </td>

        <td>
            Address
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let user of userList$ | async">
        <td>
            {{user.name}}
        </td>

        <td>
            {{user.address}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

My question is how can I sort the observable based on name:

```
sortByName(){
  this.userList$ = this.userList$.sort((a,b)=>{

  return 
 }
}
```

A note that I am dispatching the action after form submission:

```
submit() {
    if (this.searchForm.valid) {
    this.store.dispatch(new GET_USER_LIST());
   }
  }
```

I have tried to use map operator but It doesn't work for me.

Please suggest me how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` rxjs operaor (not the `map` js function!) along with js `sort()`, for example:

```
this.users = this.userList$
  .pipe(
     map((users) => users.sort((a,b) => a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1))
  );
```

Comment: this will return an Array of object and I can't loop the data in table using async as shown in my code

Comment: So why not removing the `async` ? You already resolve the data for proccessing, there is no reason to do it also in the template.

Comment: I got you. But I am setting the dispatch() function after form submission and getting the userList$ which I am instantly displaying in html. I have the question.

Comment: I have updated my question. I would be happy to remove async if I can manage to display data after form submission. Is there any way to display data without using async pipe after I submit form @TheUnreal

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried the map operator, but you don't show your attempt. Map should be perfect for your use case.

There are a number of ways to do this, one way could be to create a new observable that derives from userList$ and to keep things reactive you can use a subject to keep track of the sorting criteria.

```
sortedList$: Observable<User>;
sortBy$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
constructor() { 
  this.sortedList$ = this.userList$.pipe(
    latestFrom(sortBy$), 
    map(([users, sortBy]) => { 
     // here you have access to users and the sortBy string.
     // do your sorting and return the sorted user list. 
    })); 
}

sortByName(): void { this.sortBy$.next('name') }
```

In your template you can then subscribe to sortedList$ with the async pipe.

Another way to do this, since you are already using NGXS is to add the sorting state to your store and create a selector that combines the userList selector and your sort selector and returns a sorted list.